# PHP function to determine if a variable is a number(not hex or other numericals that have letters in them)

Tags: php, double, numeric

is there a php function other than [**is_numeric**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) that determines if a variable is a number(not hex).  Because i a need to verify if a variable is a number/decimal, no hex or other type of numericals that have letters in them.

Comment: We are not google, but I think you want [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) or a regex

Comment: I would be tempted to combine tests with 'is_numeric' to exclude the ones not wanted. i.e. is_numeric and not hexadecimal etc. Why do this rather than write your own? Identifying all the valid number types is not trivial especially floating point formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in function that I know of.  A regular expression can catch it pretty easy, `^\d+(\.\d*)?$` (will match '0.123', but not '.123').

But here's another alternative strategy.

```
<?php

function isDigit($var) {
    return ((string)$var == (float)$var);
}

var_export(isDigit('123.3')); // true
var_export(isDigit('-321'));  // true
var_export(isDigit('0xFFF')); // false
```

**UPDATE:**

I just remembered [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), which I think offers the best solution.

```
<?php 
if (filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) !== false) {
    echo 'is float';
} else {
    echo 'is not float';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [**`ctype_digit`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php). This will returns TRUE if every character in the string text is a decimal digit, FALSE otherwise.

Comment: `ctype_digit` does not work with decimals or negative numbers, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Make it by yourself as follows:

```
<?php
function is_number($n = null){
    if (is_null($n)){
        return false;
    }
    if (is_int($n)){
        return true;
    }
    $n = $n.'';
    $decimal = explode('.',$n);
    if (is_int($decimal[0]*1) && is_int($decimal[1]*1)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}

if (is_number(1.2)){
    echo "yes";
}
else{
    echo "no";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Xzm7pL)